# Como obter um número limitado de ocorrências com DOM?

Tags: php, dom

Estou fazendo parser de um site, quero obter alguns dados dele, os dados estão estruturados da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="interesses">
<span class="tipo" >Tipo 1</span>
<span class="tipo" >Tipo 1</span>
<span class="tipo" >Tipo 2</span>
<span class="tipo" >Tipo 2</span>
<span class="tipo" >Tipo 3</span>
<span class="tipo" >Tipo 3</span>
</div>
```

Eu quero pegar as informações dento da `span` `tipo`, então usei o DOM:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://exemplo.com");
    $DOM =  new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML('<meta charset="utf-8">'.$html);
    $xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);
        $tipo = $xpath->query('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "tipo")]');
        $arrValues = array_map(null,iterator_to_array($tipo))
        foreach($arrValues as $value){
            echo $value[0]->nodeValue."<br />";
        }
```

Funciona!

Mas o problema é que na página de origem, como vocês viram, tem dois "tipo 1" e dois "tipos 2" e assim por diante, o site sempre gera informações duplicadas, mas só me interessa mostrar um de cada, ou seja, apenas um "Tipo 1" e outro "Tipo 2" e assim por diante.
Mas está vindo tudo e não faço ideia do que fazer pra impedir a duplicidade.

***Atualização:***

O `array_unique` que o @Miguel Angelo ensinou, funcionou!
Mas agora imagine o seguinte cenário:
Existe 1 padaria online, que vende vários tipos de pão doce: com coco e sem coco.
O comprador então escolhe dois pães um com coco e outro sem coco, a estrutura HTML ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<div class="interesses">
<span class="tipo" >Pão Doce</span>
<span class="tipo" >Com coco</span>
<span class="tipo" >Pão Doce</span>
<span class="tipo" >Com coco</span>
<span class="tipo" >Pão Doce</span>
<span class="tipo" >Sem coco</span>
<span class="tipo" >Pão Doce</span>
<span class="tipo" >Sem coco</span>
</div>
```

Eu quero agora, mostrar ao usuário somente os 2 tipos de pão que ele pediu:

> Item 1: Pão doce com coco, Item 2: pão doce sem coco.

O `DOM` me retornaria algo como:

> Item 1: Pão doce com coco, Item 2: pão doce com coco, item 3: pão doce sem coco, Item 4: pão doce sem
>   coco

Se usar o `unique` da dica do @Miguel Angelo, o "tipo" só vai se repetir uma vez, ou seja:

> Item 1: Pão Doce Com coco, Item 2: Sem Coco.

Ou seja, se tiver dois dos mesmo tipos de pão, ele só vai mostrar ou tudo ou apenas 1, mas quero que exiba apenas um grupo de cada: "Pão doce com coco" e tire a repetição "Pão doce com coco" mas mantenha o "Pão doce sem coco" e remova novamente o "Pão doce sem coco" duplicado.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não dá pra usar [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php)?

Exemplo:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://exemplo.com");
$DOM =  new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML('<meta charset="utf-8">'.$html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);
    $tipo = $xpath->query('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "tipo")]');
    $arrValues = array_unique(array_map(
            function ($el) { return $el->nodeValue; },
            iterator_to_array($tipo)));
    foreach($arrValues as $value){
        echo $value."<br />";
    }
```

**Edição para resolver problema adicional:**

O segundo problema parece ser o de concatenar os elementos de um array, de 2 a 2 elementos. Ou seja, uma array assim:

```
[ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
```

Teria que ficar assim:

```
[ "ab", "cd" ]
```

Antes de passar para o `array_unique`.

Para isso fiz a seguinte função:

```
function func_concat_N_a_N($num, $array) {
  $length = count($array);
  $item = "";
  $result = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $item = ($i % $num)==0 ? $array[$i] : $item." ".$array[$i];
    if ((($i+1) % $num)==0)
      $result[] = $item;
  }
  return $result;
};
```

Que será usada no código original assim:

```
$arrValues = array_unique(
               // aqui está ela sendo utilizada
               func_concat_N_a_N(
                   // indicando que será de 2 a 2
                   2,
                   // array que queremos unir de 2 a 2
                   array_map(
                       function ($el) { return $el->nodeValue; },
                       iterator_to_array($tipo))));
```

[Demonstração online do código acima](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/306510700b9d5feefa0a6085223093faebfd7767)

Comment: Não conhecia o `array_unique`, mesmo assim ele não funcionou, exibiu apenas 1 ocorrência pra 7 que tem atualmente no site.

Comment: Como array_map estava com um único array, eu o alterei passando uma função para obter somente o conteúdo do elemento, em forma de string, antes de passar pro array_unique... vê ai se agora funciona.

Comment: Funcionou!
Agora leia por gentileza a atualização, pra ver se você pode também me tirar esta dúvida.